# Creating a dictionary from one excel workbook, matching the keys with another workbook, paste values

Tags: python-3.x

I hope someone can provide a little help. I'm attempting to pull data from one excel workbook, titled DownTime, and create a dictionary of coil(product) numbers matched with "codes" that coil has experienced. I have been able to accomplish this part, it's pretty straight forward.

The part that is tripping me up, is how to match the coil numbers with a different excel workbook, and paste in the corresponding "codes".

So here is what I have so far:

```
import openpyxl
from collections import defaultdict

DT = openpyxl.load_workbook('DownTime.xlsm')
bl2 = DT.get_sheet_by_name('BL2')
CS = openpyxl.load_workbook('CoilSummary.xlsm')
line = CS.get_sheet_by_name('BL2')
#opening needed workbooks with specific worksheets


coil =[]
rc = []
code = defaultdict(set)
cnum = ''
next_row = 2
col = 32

for row in range(2, bl2.max_row + 1):
    coil = bl2['K' + str(row)].value
    rc = bl2['D' + str(row)].value
    code[coil].add(rc)
    # Creating a dictionary that represents each coil with corresponding codes

for key,value in code.items():   
    cnum = line['B' + str(row)].value
    if cnum == key:
        line.write(next_row, col, value)
        next_row+=1
# Attempting to match coil numbers with dictionary and column B
# if the key is present, paste the value in column AF    

CS.close()
DT.close()
```

A sample output of the dictionary looks as follows:

```
('M30434269': {106, 107, 173}, 'M30434270': {132, 424, 106, 173, 188}, 'M30434271': {194, 426, 202, 106, 173}})
```

Only there are about 22,000 entries.

So to reiterate what I want to accomplish:

I want to take this dictionary that I made from the workbook DownTime, match the keys with a column in CoilSummary, and if the keys match the cell entry, paste the value into a blank cell at the end of the table.

Example:

```
"CoilNum"      "Date"         "Shift"  "info1" "info2"  "Code"
M30322386   03/03/2017 06:48:30  3       1052     1722   '    '
M30322390   03/03/2017 05:18:26  3       703      1662   '    '
```

I would like to match the "CoilNum" with the keys in the dictionary, and paste the values into "Code".

I hope I explained that well enough. Any help with the code, or point to a website for reference, would be very much appreciated. I just don't want to have to type all of these codes in by hand!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After much research and trial and error, accidentally corrupting excel files and getting generally frustrated with python and excel, I figured it out. Here is what I have:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# importing tools needed for the code to work
import pyexcel as pe
from collections import defaultdict
import openpyxl as op


coil =''
rc = {}
code = defaultdict(list)
next_row = 2
col = 33
cnum = []
temp = ''



def write_data(code,cnum):
    ''' Used to open a given sheet in a workbook. The code will then compare values 
collected from one column in a specific sheet referred to as "coils" and compares it to a dictionary where the key's are also "coils."
    If the coil number matches, the code will then paste the values in a new workbook. From here the values can be copied by hand and pasted into the excel file of choice.'''
    sheet = pe.get_sheet(file_name="CoilSummaryTesting.xlsx")
    next_row = 2
    lst = []

    while next_row <= len(cnum):
        for key in code.keys(): 
            for step in cnum: 
                if str(step) == str(key):
                    for val in code.values():
                        temp = val
                        lst.append(temp)
                        next_row+=1  


                if step!=key:
                    break
        break

    for item in lst:
        sublist = (" ").join(str(item))
        sheet.row+= [sublist]
    sheet.save_as("CoilSummaryTest.xlsx")
    print("\nCoils Compared: ",next_row)            



def open_downtime():
    ''' Pull data from a second excel file to obtain the coil numbers with corresponding downtime codes'''

    DT = op.load_workbook('DownTime.xlsm')
    bl2 = DT.get_sheet_by_name('BL2')
    n = 1

    for row in bl2.iter_cols(min_col=11,max_col=11):
        for colD in row:
            code[colD.offset(row=1,column=0).value].append(colD.offset(row=1,column=-7).value
        n+=1
    print('\nNumber of rows in DownTime file: ',n)  
    return code

def open_coil():
    '''Opens the first workbook and sheet to know how many rows are needed for coil comparision.'''

    i = 1
    CSR = op.load_workbook('CoilSummaryTesting.xlsx')
    line_read = CSR.get_sheet_by_name('BL2')


    for rows in line_read.iter_cols(min_col=2, max_col=2):
      for col in rows:

            cnum.append(col.offset(row=1,column=0).value)
            i+=1

    print('\nNumber of rows in CoilSummary file: ',i)    



    return write_data(open_downtime(),cnum)


def main():
    sheet = open_coil()



if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

I understand this is probably not the shortest version of this code and there are probably a lot of ways to get it to paste directly into the excel file of my choice, but I couldn't figure that part out yet.

What I did differently is using pyexcel. This proved to be the easiest when it came to just pasting values into rows or columns. Using join, I broke the generated list of lists up to allow each sublist to be inserted in its own row. I currently settled on having the generated rows saved to a different excel workbook because having continuously corrupted workbooks during this exploration; however, if anyone knows how to manipulate this code to eliminate the last step of having to copy the rows to paste into the desired workbook, please let me know.